# how to compile a program with a given file.a

Tags: c, cmake, executable

I did a program that need some functions from a file that the staff gives us.
the file is libmap.a.
I developed some modules that use functions from the libmap file.

how can I compile it?
Some friends said me that I need to change something to the Cmake file.
is someone know what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You do not compile, only link with the library file.

for gcc you need to use `-l` option in your case `-lmap` and if needed set the path using `-L` option.

in Cmake you need to set your library search path:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(your_target "directory")
```

and the add the library

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(your_target map)
```